# Location of logs in Windows

Tags: logging, log-files, windows-event-log

What is the difference between

```
C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles
```

and

```
C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs
```

?

Are there any other important system log locations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs => In here are the Event Viewer Files

[image: Location of Event Viewer by doing Right Click on the Event category and then click on Properties]

C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles => There are other kind of logs non OS related.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

C:\Windows\System32\LogFiles is for Windows component and application logs.

C:\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs is for the event logs.

You might have other logging locations if you have IIS installed, have Exchange Server installed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You'll also find some setup/configuration logs under `C:\Windows\Logs`.